# Asking for some reference for square of a graph Laplacian matrix. ($L^2$ or $L^{\dagger^2}$)

Tags: linear-algebra, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-laplacian

I am looking for some information regarding Laplacian squared of a graph. ($L^2 or L^{\dagger^2}$) I couldn't find anything special. Specially the graphs with positive weights on edges.

Any related reference is very welcomed to be posted here.

Comment: What motivates this Question?  It would greatly improve it if the Reader were given some context.  Certainly polynomials of the Laplacian matrix have some applications.

Comment: I want to draw a relationship between eigenvalues of $L^{\dagger^2}$ and inverse of degree of nodes of the graph. For example, something similar to Schur–Horn theorem on majorization of diagonal elements and degree of nodes.

Comment: Did you find any?